# Split a dataframe into two groups by column

Tags: r

I am trying to separate columns in a dataframe to two dataframes based on the sum of each column

Here is what I have tried:

```
 sum_each_col <- apply(originalDF,2,sum)
 ave_sum <- mean(sum_each_col)

 col_k1 <- data.frame()
 col_k2 <- data.frame()

 apply(originalDF,2,function(x){
 if(sum(x) <=ave_sum){
    cbind(col_k1,as.data.frame(x))
  }
 else {
    cbind(col_k2,as.data.frame(x))
  }
 }
 )
```

Original DF:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A  1   2    1    2    2
B  1   2    1    2    2  
C  1   2    1    2    2
```

Expect output:
    col_k1:

```
   col1 col3 
 A  1     1    
 B  1     1     
 C  1     1
```

col_k2:

```
    co2 col4 col5
  A  2    2    2
  B  2    2    2 
  C  2    2    2
```

Comment: the data.frames are dimensionless, so cbind will not work as the number of  rows is different.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
#there is a function colMeans that calculates the mean of each column
index <- colMeans(DF) < mean(colMeans(DF))
```

And then:

```
> DF[index]
  col1 col3
A    1    1
B    1    1
C    1    1
```

And:

```
> DF[!index]
  col2 col4 col5
A    2    2    2
B    2    2    2
C    2    2    2
```

---

data:

```
DF <- read.table(header=T, text=' col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A  1   2    1    2    2
B  1   2    1    2    2  
C  1   2    1    2    2')
```

Comment: The `which` isn't needed `index <- colMeans(DF) < mean(colMeans(DF))` will do fine, then `DF[index]` and `DF[!index]`